# Hiding deleted objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following use case: There's a class called Template and with that class I can create instances of the ActualObject class (ActualObject copies its inital data from the Template). The Template class has a list of Product:s.

Now here comes the tricky part, the user should be able to delete Products from the database but these deletions may not affect the content of a Template. In other words, even if a Product is deleted, the Template should still have access to it. This could be solved by adding a flag "deleted" to the Product. If a Product is deleted, then it may not be searched explicitly from the database, but it can be fetched implicitly (for example via the reference in the Template class).

The idea behind this is that when an ActualObject is created from a template, the user is notified in the user interface that "The Template X had a Product Z with the parameters A, B and C, but this product has been deleted and cannot be added as such in ActualObject Z".

My problem is how I should mark these deleted objects as deleted. Before someone suggests that just update the delete flag instead of doing an actual delete query, my problem is not that simple. The delete flag and its behaviour should exist in all POJOs, not just in Product. This means I'll be getting cascade problems. For example, if I delete a Template, then the Products should also be deleted and each Product has a reference to a Price-object which also should be deleted and each Price may have a reference to a VAT-object and so forth. All these cascaded objects should be marked as deleted.

My question is how can I accomplish this in a sensible manner. Going through every object (which are being deleted) checking each field for references which should be deleted, going through their references etc is quite laborious and bugs are easy to slip in.

I'm using Hibernate, I was wondering if Hibernate would have any such inbuilt features. Another idea that I came to think of was to use hibernate interceptors to modify an actual SQL delete query to an update query (I'm not even 100% sure this is possible). My only concern is that does Hibernate rely on cascades in foreign keys, in other words, the cascaded deletes are done by the database and not by hibernate.

Comment: Why do you need to cascade?
Just mark the Product and then from the Pojo floow the foreign keys to the Product or on load from db filter by the deleted flag in Product.
ie hold the delted flag in one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is how I should mark these
>   deleted objects as deleted.

I think you have choosen a very complex way to solve the task. It would be more easy to introduce `ProductTemplate`. Place into this object all required properties you need. And also you need here a reference to a `Product` instance. Than instead of marking `Product` you can just delete it (and delete all other entities, such as prices). And, of course, you should clean reference in `ProductTemplate`. When you are creating an instance of `ActualObject` you will be able to notify the user with appropriate message.

Comment: My example was just one use case, there are many more and therefore we would like to find a more general solution.

Comment: Restricting of class roles is a general strategy. You can follow it every day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to make things much more complicated than they should be... anyway, what you're trying to do is handling Hibernate *events*, take a look at **Chapter 12 of Hibernate  Reference**, you can choose to use **interceptors** or the **event system**.
In any case... well good luck :)

Comment: Like I mentioned, I had thought of interceptors, but my concern is whether or not hibernate uses foreign key cascades in the database, in which case I cannot cover all delete operations by using interceptors.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Deletable {
  public void delete();
}
```

Have all your deletable objects implement this interface. In their implementations, update the `deleted` flag and have them call their children's `delete()` method also - which implies that the children must be `Deletable` too.

Of course, upon implementation you'll have to manually figure which children are `Deletable`. But this should be straightforward, at least.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, you add an @OneToMany relationship between the template and the product, and select your cascade rules, you will be able to delete all associated products for a given template.  In your product class, you can add the "deleted" flag as you suggested.  This deleted flag would be leveraged by your service/dao layer e.g. you could leverage a getProdcuts(boolean includeDeleted) type concept to determine if you should include the "deleted" records for return.  In this fashion you can control what end users see, but still expose full functionality to internal business users.

Comment: I missed the cascade update of the "deleted" property for child objects.  What if you externalized this concept into a separate object, for example "Deleted" and use shared references from the parent and child.  This way when you update the parent's "Deleted" object, all associated children would have their reference updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The flag to delete should be a part of the Template Class itself. That way all the Objects that you create have a way to be flagged as alive or deleted. The marking of the Object to be deleted, should go higher up to the base class.